# GWT Arraylist<object> serialization

Tags: gwt, serialization

I have two different model class,

```
public class ModelDto implements IsSerializable{
     public ModelDto {}
     private Integer id;
     private String name;
     private ArrayList<Test> name;
}

public class Test implements IsSerializable{
     public Test {}
     private Integer id;
     private String name;
     private ArrayList<Test> name;
}
```

I want to make a RPC call like

```
ModelDto getModel();
```

How to achieve this? I know that the issue is basic serialization. but I want to know that how to pass a ArrayList in RPC If not posible any alternatives?.

Comment: Which bit of the GWT RPC demo is giving you a problem?  https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC

Comment: I use same tutorial but I cant pass a ArrayList<Test> on client side there always null

Comment: There should not be any issue in serializing ArrayList. Can you post the code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Passing an ArrayList<Test> should work just fine. Could the problem be somewhere else? Can you include the code for your remote service implementation in your question?

Comment: Have you tried using List instead of ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like problem with your `implements IsSerializable` I suspect your class  not implement `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable.`

It should implements either `java.io.Serializable` or GWT `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable.`(No problem with both together).

And about your default constructor .It should an `empty constructor.`
e.g

```
 public ModelDto() {

}
```

Most of the problems raises with these two points only if you still facing the issue after made the above changes like `package structures`...etc please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534484/gwt-rpc-serializationexception).