# Apache Tomcat AccessDeniedException on accessing folder

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, gwt

I am currently trying to deploy a GWT web app to a tomcat instance, and the program isn't running correctly. On close examination of the tomcat logs, it looks like Tomcat is running into a AccessDeniedException.

> SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type
>   'java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException' was not included in the set of
>   types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class
>   object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not
>   be serialized.: instance = java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
>   /luceneIndex

I am perplexed however, as the folder should be easily accessible to tomcat.

```
drwxrwxrwx 4 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar 14 20:32 SearchTest
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat tomcat  602 Mar 12 20:14 SearchTest.css
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat tomcat 3038 Mar 13 23:13 SearchTest.html
drwxrwxrwx 5 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar 14 20:24 WEB-INF
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat tomcat 1082 Mar 12 20:14 favicon.ico
drwxrwxrwx 2 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar 14 20:24 luceneFiles
drwxrwxrwx 2 tomcat tomcat 4096 Mar 14 20:24 luceneIndex
```

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: You may wish to have a look at [GWT - RPC SerializationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534484/gwt-rpc-serializationexception). A google search on _com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.serializationexception type was not included_ finds quite a few others that may be of assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using 'java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException' in your client-side code? The GWT compiler translates all the client-side Java code into JavaScript. Since not all Java functionalities are available in a web browser, GWT only supports a subset of the Java runtime library.

You can take a look at these two page [JRE Compatablity](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html) and [JRE Emulation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).

As far as I can tell, none of the classes within java.nio package are emulated. That might be the reason you got your error.