# GWT - RPC SerializationException with class object

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-syncproxy

I am currently trying to use the SyncProxy library to test services of my app, in order to do load testing with JMeter. The app works fine, I am running it on localhost.

I already managed to make some calls, but only when the parameters where

this is the error :

> Type 'net.gicm.ector.shared.beans.Utilisateur' was not included in the
>   set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or
>   its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type
>   will not be serialized.

Here is the piece of code where I make the call :

```
 final Utilisateur user = new Utilisateur();
 user.setUser("C2984");

 TableauDeBordServiceAsync tableauDeBordServiceAsync = (TableauDeBordServiceAsync) SyncProxy
          .newProxyInstance(TableauDeBordServiceAsync.class, MODULE_BASE_URL, GET_SERVICE_NAME_2);
 tableauDeBordServiceAsync.ongletRealisationListeControle(plan, user, codeSI, numStructure, synthese, colonneAtrier, ordre, numeroPagination, filtre, new AsyncCallback<List<List<String>>>() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(caught);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<List<String>> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(result);

    }

 });
```

I looked at this thread, and tried to find where could I do something wrong : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9534704/4628136

My class implements the `Serializable` interface, has a default empty constructor, and is in the client package.

```
public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {
   ...
   public Utilisateur() {
   }
   ...
}
```

But actually, I don't see anything about that `Utilisateur` class in the gwt.rpc files.

Comment: You can get that error also if `Utilisateur` aggregates types which are not Serializable/have no-arg constructor.

Comment: Well, there is only one and it does have a no-arg constructor and it implements the Serializable interface

Comment: Is your class in Utilisateur in 'shared' packet?

Comment: yes, it is in the "shared" package

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable
```

Your class would be like:

```
public class Utilisateur implements IsSerializable, Serializable {
   ...
   public Utilisateur() {
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: I still have the same error, even when implementing the `IsSerializable` interface

Comment: Try to put `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` in your `Utilisateur`class

Comment: Has your class `Utilisateur` intern class references? I mean, something like `private MyClass myClass;`? All internal references must be also serializable

Comment: Nope, it hasn't

Comment: Can you please post the complete `Utilisateur`class?

Comment: What happens with classes `Habilitation`, `Structure` and `InfoUserOsireBean`? are all of them serializable and part of `shared`package?

Comment: yes, they both are serializable, and are part of the shared package

Comment: If all your classes implements `IsSerializable, Serializable`, my last suggestion is to be sure you have removed all cache from your browser...otherwise I've no idea :(

Comment: Actually, this is the scenario : Everything works in the browser (the application itself works), but when I try to simulate a user from my JUnit, this is where I get the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the attributes of this class are also serialized.