# Getting GWT RPC Serialization Error while populating liststore of ComboBox

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using GWT 2.9 and I am getting below error

SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.xyz.nos.model.NosOptionModel' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.xyz.nos.model.NosOptionModel@6cad8f33

SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.xyz.nos.model.NosOptionModel' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.xyz.nos.model.NosOptionModel@5fc5e111

SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.xyz.nos.model.NosCaseDetailModel' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.xyz.nos.model.NosCaseDetailModel@af3642f

SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.xyz.nos.model.CountryGroupModel' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.xyz.nos.model.CountryGroupModel@51987007

SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.xyz.nos.model.NosUser' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.xyz.nos.model.NosUser@28bbfa7f

I am doing GWT RPC for populating liststore of combobox and getting above exception while performing it from EntryPoint class. All the above classes are Pojo's and all the fields of these classes are Serializable

I have tried all possible solutions given in **[GWT - RPC SerializationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534484/gwt-rpc-serializationexception/9534704#9534704)**

I have defined my service as below

```
public interface INamedComboListDataProvider<M> extends RemoteService {
    public List<M> load(String name);
}
```

I also have checked my serializationWhitelist and it only contain following 25 classes

```
{class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TreeListenerCollection=true, class java.lang.String=true, class com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException=true, class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FocusListenerCollection=true, class com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RpcTokenException=true, class java.util.LinkedList=true, class java.lang.RuntimeException=false, class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.LoadListenerCollection=true, class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ClickListenerCollection=true, class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormHandlerCollection=true, class java.lang.Throwable=false, class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.KeyboardListenerCollection=true, class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MouseListenerCollection=true, class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TabListenerCollection=true, class java.util.Vector=true, class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ChangeListenerCollection=true, class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ScrollListenerCollection=true, class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupListenerCollection=true, class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MouseWheelListenerCollection=true, class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList=true, class java.lang.Exception=false, class java.util.ArrayList=true, class java.util.Collections$EmptyList=true, class java.util.Collections$SingletonList=true, class com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TableListenerCollection=true}
```

I also have added project folder structure below
client
model
service
services
util
Common.gwt.xml
Main.gwt.xml

Can anybody guide me where I am going wrong and why does the serializationwhilteList does not contain the pojo models ?

Comment: Is this a new service you're creating?

Comment: Yes I have created a new service.